# How do I give access to Google Cloud Dataprep?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataprep

I have created a flow in Cloud Dataprep, job executed. All fine.

However, my colleagues, who also has owner role in this GCP project, are not able to see the flow I created. I'm not able to find sharing options anywhere.

How should it be setup so that Dataprep flow can be worked on by multiple users?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE from September 2018 onwards**

Sharing is now available. See the answer from @justbeez below https://stackoverflow.com/a/55386000/945789 for details.

**No longer relevant - original answer prior to this release below**

At the current time this is not possible. There were a bunch of new features released Jan 23, 2018 but sharing flows and/or datasets is still not there. Given it's still Beta keep an eye on releases as they seem to be big jumps: https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/release-notes.

There are two workarounds I know of at the moment:

1. Whenever you create flows, do so under a shared/generic Google login. Google don't recommend this as it's not great security, but it's the only way to have live access with more than one person. Of course that user will also need access to your project.
2. Periodically export your flow as a zip (three dots menu when you hover a flow) and store that on a shared drive. You can import that flow at the flows menu. I'm not sure whether export and/or import was new in the Jan 2018 release or not, but I didn't notice it prior to that.

Answer (score 1):

We've been using sharing at the Flow level since it was added in September 2018 (check the changelog). You get to this option from the kabob menu on the individual flow:
[image: Example of the sharing option in the Flow menu]

From there, you'll get a sharing menu you can use (keep in mind, you can only share with people who are in the project and have suitable permissions):
[image: Flow-level sharing dialog]

From there, you can see either all flows by default or just those that are shared:
[image: Flow ownership sharing example]

Note that there's currently only one shared permission level, which is Collaborator.  This means the person you share with can work with the flow, add recipes, etc.—but they don't have the option of renaming the flow or managing sharing.  The recently added Folders option doesn't support sharing at all.

Full details on sharing flows can be found here:
https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Overview-of-Sharing_118228675